# How avoid Error: Cannot find module ‘express’

Tags: node.js, express

First I installed express in this way: `nmp install -g express`
I check my Path variable and it is set "`C:\Users\Eventi\AppData\Roaming\npm`".

This is the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs=require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

and this is the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Eventi\Desktop\Node.js\Progetti\ProveNodeJS\NodeJSProve\HelloWord.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: provide the code snippet which produces the error.

Comment: Don't install packages that you are going to `require()` globally (which is what the `-g` means). [See also](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally).

Comment: Going off of what @robertklep said, install express locally with npm install express.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "require" it in your application. Write `var express = require('express');` then initialize express with `var app = express();`

Comment: Did you install it correctly? In your question you have nmp, but should be npm install -g express